# asp.net core 2.0 model validation not validating data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-validation

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 default model validation and it seems not working with the `ModelState.IsValid` always true despite having wrong data in model.

```
[HttpPost("abc")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Abc([FromBody]AbcViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(ModelState); }
    ...
}

public class AbcViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id is required")]
    [Range(100, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I post data from Angular app, the values are mapping to model correctly but if `Id` is "0" or less than 100, both the `Required` and `Range` validators aren't working and `ModelState.IsValid` is always true. What I am missing?

Comment: You need to set the Id to nullable else the value will be defaulted to 0 even if the client don't send an Id in the request.

Comment: I've copied your code exactly, and I can't reproduce your problem. One thing to note, however: `Required` checks that a value won't be `null`, an empty string, or whitespace. In your case, `Id` is a non-nullable `int`, so that will always provide a value.

Comment: Alright I got the case for required as it should be nullable to work. But what about the Range attribute, why it's not working?

Comment: @AliShahzad, same for me, `Range` works as expected - when `Id` is outside of range or not supplied (zero by default) i get a `400 BadRequest`
POST /api/values/abc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61154
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 62024574-776a-4e1b-93b7-6a7bb78ecfca

{
 "Id": 1
}
400 Bad Request
{"Id":["Invalid Id"]}

Comment: @ironstone13 But it's not working for me which I guess I'm missing something

Comment: Share us the project which coudl reproduce your issue.

Comment: @AliShahzad Were you ever able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `services.AddMvcCore()`, then you need to explicitly set up your application to perform validation with data annotations:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
         .AddDataAnnotations()
         /* etc. */;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Collin that fixed a similar problem that we were experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same model property that you defined in the model and facing the same issue. I made one change in the property and defined the DataMember attribute on the property like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Id is required")]
[Range(100, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id")]
[DataMember(Name = "Id")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

It's working as expected, validating the range values. Try this, hope it will resolve the issue that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I also fought with this problem and what helped in my case was adding this in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(opt=> {
    opt.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes = true;
});
```

Just be carefull about the outcome - if you want to get automatic BadRequest you have to use `[ApiController]` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#model-state). Otherwise you have to check `ModelState.IsValid` property.

Comment: `AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes` is obsolete from 2.2 and not found in 3.1. Any idea how to use it in 3.1?

Comment: According to https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18438#issuecomment-638494816 validation of top level nodes is enabled by default when using any of mentioned services.